# Why QGIS 2.12 "forgets" selection colour opacity settings?

Tags: qgis, layers, style, qgis-2.12, transparency-opacity

I have few vector layers which I need to edit frequently. I'd like to be able to see through the layer when it's selected. I changed selection colour from both: Project Properties General settings and Options-->Canvas&Legend settings. For both of these I changed the opacity to 40% --> click OK --> save. It works for a while, but after I restart QGIS, the opacity is still set to 40% in both settings, but I can't see through the selection. So QGIS kind of thinks it's still showing transparent selection colour, but it actually is not. So is this a bug in QGIS or am I just missing something?

[image]

If I change the selection colour opacity from 40% to 39% and click "OK" the layer comes transparent again. I'm working with PostGIS layers, but this same problem occurs with shapefiles also.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that this issue has been resolved in **QGIS 2.12.2** where the opacity of the chosen colour is still remembered after restarting QGIS:

---

- Before restarting QGIS and setting opacity to 10%

[image: Before restart]

- After restarting QGIS

[image: After restart]